# How can I read a String line by line and replace particular line with another particular String

Tags: java, string

How can I read String line by line and replace particular line with another particular String?
For example:

```
String myString = "This" +"\nis" + "\nonly" + "\nthe" + "\nexample";
```

And I want to read them line by line start from the top and replace each one such "This" ->> "newThis"    "is" ->> "newIs" , and so on.

Comment: Unclear. You do not specify how the result should be stored. As to splitting the source on newlines, regexes are a solution here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `split` method:

```
String[] yourStringAsArray = myString.split("\n")
```

Then you can iterate over your array like that:

```
for(String s : yourStringAsArray){
    s.replaceAll("oldValue", "newValue")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can split the String on the "\n" character, replace each element you desire, then piece the string back together like so:

```
String[] lines = myString.split("\n");
// Replace lines here
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String line : lines) {
    sb.append(line + "\n");
}
// Haven't dealt with the trailing "\n", but I leave that as an exercise to the user.
myString = sb.toString();
```

Comment: Oops! Sorry...see edit.  Got mind mixed between collections and arrays. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can store it as a String[] by using:
    String[] s_array = myString.split("\n");

Then access each element individually

Answer (score 0):

This solution is based on Java 8 Stream API and lambdas.

```
public static final String DELIMITER = "\n";
public static final Pattern SPLIT_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(DELIMITER);
public static final Function<String, String> TRANSFORM_STRING = (String text) ->
        SPLIT_PATTERN.splitAsStream(text)
                .map(s -> "new" + s)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(DELIMITER));

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String inputText = "This" + "\nis" + "\nonly" + "\nthe" + "\nexample";
    final String outputText = TRANSFORM_STRING.apply(inputText);
    System.out.println(outputText);
}
```